# Primefaces theme configuration

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am studying primefaces themes on Primefaces user guide.
https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/primefaces/primefaces_users_guide_3_3.pdf At pag. 457 you can read: "Once you've downloaded the theme, configure PrimeFaces to use it

```
<context-param>

    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>

    <param-value>aristo</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Where should I put it? Into the webpage file I am developing?
I choosed the jar file of Redmond theme and I imported it into my Eclipse Dynamic web project, but I don't see any improvement.

The Primefaces example I am testing is: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml

**Car.java**

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Car {

        private String model;
        private int year;
        private String manufacturer;
        private String color;

        public Car(String model, int year, String manufacturer, String color) {
                this.model = model;
                this.year = year;
                this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
                this.color = color;
        }

        public String getModel() {
                return model;
        }

        public void setModel(String model) {
                this.model = model;
        }

        public int getYear() {
                return year;
        }

        public void setYear(int year) {
                this.year = year;
        }

        public String getManufacturer() {
                return manufacturer;
        }

        public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
                this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        }

        public String getColor() {
                return color;
        }

        public void setColor(String color) {
                this.color = color;
        }
}
```

**TableBean.java**

```
package classi;

import java.io.Serializable;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.UUID;  
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;


@ManagedBean(name="tableBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TableBean implements Serializable
{  
    private final static String[] colors;  

    private final static String[] manufacturers;  

    private List<Car> carsSmall;  
    static {  
        colors = new String[10];  
        colors[0] = "Black";  
        colors[1] = "White";  
        colors[2] = "Green";  
        colors[3] = "Red";  
        colors[4] = "Blue";  
        colors[5] = "Orange";  
        colors[6] = "Silver";  
        colors[7] = "Yellow";  
        colors[8] = "Brown";  
        colors[9] = "Maroon";  

        manufacturers = new String[10];  
        manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";  
        manufacturers[1] = "BMW";  
        manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";  
        manufacturers[3] = "Audi";  
        manufacturers[4] = "Renault";  
        manufacturers[5] = "Opel";  
        manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";  
        manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";  
        manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";  
        manufacturers[9] = "Ford";  
    }  



    public TableBean() {  
        carsSmall = new ArrayList<Car>();  

        populateRandomCars(carsSmall, 9);  
    }  

    private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size) {  
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)  
            list.add(new Car(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear(), getRandomManufacturer(), getRandomColor()));  
    }  

    public List<Car> getCarsSmall() {  
        return carsSmall;  
    }  

    private int getRandomYear() {  
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);  
    }  

    private String getRandomColor() {  
        return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];  
    }  

    private String getRandomManufacturer() {  
        return manufacturers[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];  
    }  

    private String getRandomModel() {  
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);  
    }  
}
```

**table.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h:form>  
    <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">  
        <p:column headerText="Model">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Year">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Manufacturer">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Color">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />  
        </p:column>  
    </p:dataTable>  
</h:form>  
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PrimeFaces_DataTable</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>redmond</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

**Screenshot of project structure**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF7uE.png

Comment: Put the theme jar into `WEB-INF\lib`

Comment: I tried but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to put the theme jar in you WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder, I don't know how you are deploying the project, so you could have to put primefaces jar there too, so that it will be in be in the deployed project.

With the jar's in place, you then have to edit your web.xml file to indicate what theme you would use. As an example with Redmond would be:

```
<context-param>

    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>

    <param-value>redmond</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: It does not work :( I attach web.xml file to see if there are any errors

http://pastebin.com/NYdqRLxR

Comment: LOL I am sorry, I edited the wrong project web.xml file, give me some minutes

Comment: What happens when you try to access the page? it simple don't use the redmond theme?

Comment: Try removing the jar from the libs folder, if it doesn't give an error, then the configuration in web.xml isn't being loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what could be the problem then, can you edit you question and put more info of how you project is structured?

Comment: A user on a forum suggested what is the problem and I solved it as you can see in following answer. Anyway I check your answer as correct as thanks for your continuos helping :)
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 13):

A user told me I have to edit

```
<head> and </head>
```

into

```
<h:head> and </h:head>
```

It worked :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I answered by adding the fix, but I did not enter it using code tags, so the website was not showing the code. Now I fixed it

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. I was troubleshooting this problem for 2 days, but everything I tried didn't work, until I saw your answer :D

Comment: I am glad this helped you. Sometimes Java EE programming can be VERY frustrating...