# How to configure Primefaces Aristo theme to Twitter Bootstrap theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I am newbie in this techniques. I download the [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) from here. The `primefaces.jar` have only setup with the `aristo theme`. but I need to apply the `bootstrap` theme in my site. I download [twitter bootstarp](http://getbootstrap.com/) css. How to configure this theme into my `JSF primefaces`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primefaces theme configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689731/primefaces-theme-configuration)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not. However PrimeFaces already has a theme named as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2139). Also they've explained why bootstrap files shouldn't be mixed into PF in that link. If you want to apply that theme to your project, [download theme jar](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/bootstrap/1.0.8/) and configure your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Or, see that showcase example to let user to select a theme: [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/themeswitcher.jsf)

Comment: @Kukeltje eagle eyes :)