# Using PrimeFaces with Bootstrap causes changes in padding/sizing/borders

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, primefaces

Well, I disabled all themes from PrimeFaces:

```
<context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
    <param-value>none</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

I do it because I'm using bootstrap 3 and I don't want to any conflicts in jquery-ui and bootstrap layout. The problem is that PrimeFaces datatable without "themes" becomes *a white table* with black borders, if I use the `border-style:none`, the border disappears but bootstrap style border disappears as well.

Look I tried:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <p:dataTable rowKey="#{banca.id}"
                 var="banca"
                 value="#{bancaMB.beans}"
                 paginator="true"
                 emptyMessage="Não foi encontrado nenhum registro" 
                 rows="10"
                 id="dataTableBancas"
                 selection="#{bancaMB.bean}"
                 tableStyleClass="table table-striped"
                 selectionMode="single">
..
</dataTable>
```

Look my CSS:

```css
.ui-datatable thead th,
.ui-datatable tbody,
.ui-datatable tbody tr,
.ui-datatable tbody td {
    border-style: none !important;
}
```

Look my [datatable picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBEhZ.png):

[image]

Comment: If you set the PrimeFaces theme to none, PrimeFaces components will be rendered with no themes. It is not only restricted to a `<p:dataTable>` but also several PrimeFaces' UI components will go without having a theme in them. So, even if you were to coincidentally succeed to apply a decent look/layout to data tables after the theme is set to none, the rest of the components would also require paying special attention about a theme. This should not be what you may look for.  You will instead need to handle any twitter bootstrap related stuff (bootstrap layout or anything) separately anyway.

Comment: Yes, almost all other components will fail to, look and feel wise. Since bootstrap 3 switched to a different [box-sizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854259/why-did-bootstrap-3-switch-to-box-sizing-border-box), lots and lots of small ui things will fail, like icons in selectlists being wrongly positioned etc...  I doubt you want to correct all those.

Comment: so, the best solution is give up and use primefaces components with bootstrap-primefaces theme ?

Comment: Depends... What do you want to use bootstrap for? Menus? responsive ui? Components? Check e.g. this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/responsive.xhtml

Comment: I'm using bootstrap for responsive ui, component layouts and menus. I don't wanna enable "bootstrap-primefaces" because will conflict with bootstrap.

Comment: Primefaces has responsive grid to…  and combining the two require work…  maybe bootfaces is an option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213655/jsf-and-primefaces-or-bootstrap-or-bootsfaces-or-both

Comment: @shelly; still on SO? Please accept the answer then

Answer (score 2):

Almost all other components will fail to, look and feel wise. Since bootstrap 3 switched to a [different box-sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854259/why-did-bootstrap-3-switch-to-box-sizing-border-box) (border-box instead of content-box). So lots and lots of small ui things will fail in PF components, like icons in selectlists being wrongly positioned etc... It is very difficult to fix all these in my opinion.

If you want to use bootstrap for the responsive layout things, PF something similar to, called the [grid css](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml) and [more is comming](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/responsive.xhtml)