# Problems primefaces bootstrap theme render with twitter bootstrap

Tags: jsf, primefaces, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use Primefaces 5.1 with Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.4

I've added to the files following code in facelets template `<h:head>` section

```
<h:head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
```

Web.xml

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
   <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And I'm trying to use selectCheckboxMenu component

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" >
  <p:outputLabel value="Companies sector"/>
  <p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{operations.selectedSectors}" label="Choose"
                      filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px" style="margin-right: 5px">
     <f:selectItems value="#{operations.sectors}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
...
```

The render

[image]

When I remove the bootstrap

[image]

Cellpadding and cellspacing does not work as well as seen.

I tried `<f:facet name"first">` and `<f:facet name"last">` and `<f:facet name"middle">`

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Does your favourite browser correctly render `bootstrap.min.css` as it appears from those images? If yes then, some CSS classes might be mixing with some of underlying PrimeFaces CSS classes.

Comment: @Tiny Probably. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

They just don't work together, due to the new box-sizing of bootstrap 3.

See also

- [Using PrimeFaces with Bootstrap causes changes in padding/sizing/borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183661/using-primefaces-datatable-with-bootstrap-3-style)