# p:selectOneMenu is not showing the list on click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have used following set of code to develop a `<p:selectOnemenu>`. It shows by default the first item but when I click on that, nothing happens and I can't select another option from drop-down list.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="roomcategory" value="#{user.favoriteCar1}" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="520" itemLabel="BMW Series 5 - 520" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="525" itemLabel="BMW Series 5 - 525" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="535" itemLabel="BMW Series 5 - 535" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The Ui is like this but nothing happens on click

[image]

Can anybody help me  to identify the reason ?
It's the same code i have found on primefaces showcase.

Comment: Can you post the code of the user bean?

Comment: Bean is irrelevant. This is a client side error. Are there any JS errors in browser console?

Comment: @BalusC   No nothings on console..

Comment: any custom css applied? E.g. bootstrap?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes. bootstrap.js

Comment: CSS... so bootstrap.css? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183661/using-primefaces-with-bootstrap-causes-changes-in-padding-sizing-borders

Answer (score 1):

seems a layout issue. Try to add a StyleClass attribute and decrease the width of the drop-down. At the moment it's width is larger and you can not see the drop-down trigger at the right side of the list. Also it is clear that items are loaded in the list.