# Primefaces 5.0 selectOneMenu not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm using Primefaces 5.0 in my java web application. It doesn't show the drop down item list when clicked upon. However when I add panelStyle="display:block" it will show the item list but will not collapse. It remains expanded. How do I fix it?

```
<h:form id="adddisjointcat">
        <h:panelGrid cellpadding="5" columns="2" > 
            <h:outputLabel for="adddisjointcat" value="Select Category:" /> 
             <p:selectOneMenu id="adddisjointcat" value="#{addDisjointCategory.categoryName}" effect="fold" panelStyle="display:block; width:300px; margin-left:248px; margin-top:-254px;">
                  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                  <f:selectItems value="#{addDisjointCategory.classes}" />
             </p:selectOneMenu>
       </h:panelGrid>
       <p:growl id="growl" life="2000"/>
      <p:commandButton value="ADD" id="adddisjointCategory" actionListener="#{addDisjointCategory.buttonAction}" update="growl" icon="ui-icon-seek-next" ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

I'm using a bootstrap template in my application. Wonder if it has something to do with this issue (CSS override).

Also this works fine with h:selectOneMenu, only with p:selectOneMenu the issue occurs.

Any help to resolve the problem is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PrimeFaces with Bootstrap causes changes in padding/sizing/borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183661/using-primefaces-with-bootstrap-causes-changes-in-padding-sizing-borders)

Comment: If you think the p and h component are almost identical, please investigate the generated xhtml. Lots of differences